# Android Test - How I could test this function?

Tags: java, android, testing, mockito

I am doing test cases and I don't now how to test this function. Could you give me some ideas? I was trying to use Mockito but I keep getting get null. I would appreciate your help.

This is the function I want to test.

```
public static Date optDate(JSONObject json, String key) {
    if(!json.isNull(key)) {
        try {
            DateTime dt = JSONUtils.dateFormatter.withZoneUTC().parseDateTime(json.optString(key));
            Date date = dt.toDate();
            return date;
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I am testing it in this way.

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JSONUtilsTest {
    static String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
    static DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat);
    DateTime dt = JSONUtilsTest.dateFormatter.withZoneUTC().parseDateTime("2011-11-02T02:50:12.208Z");
    Date date = dt.toDate();

    @Mock
    JSONObject JSONMock = Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class);
    JSONUtils mJSONUtils = Mockito.mock(JSONUtils.class);


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        doReturn(date).when(mJSONUtils).optDate(JSONMock,"possessionDate");
    }


    @Test
    public void optDateShouldReturnValueOnValidString() {
            Date result = JSONUtils.optDate(JSONMock, "possessionDate");
            Assert.assertEquals("2011-11-02",result);

    }


}
```

*****************************EDIT 1 ***********************************************

After trying to find a correct way to test this method. I did this.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JSONUtilsTest {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    Date today = new Date();
    String todayString = dateFormat.format(today);

    @Mock
    JSONObject JSONMock = Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        when(JSONUtils.optString(JSONMock, "possessionDate")).thenReturn(todayString);

    }

    @Test
    public void optDateShouldReturnValueOnValidString() {
        Date result = JSONUtils.optDate(JSONMock, "possessionDate");
        Assert.assertEquals(today,result);
    }
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken: the only thing that you need to control here would be the `json` object. Meaning: you can/should check if those two method calls `isNull()` and `optString()` are called on the object that you provide to the method under test.

Comment: @Jägermeister How I can do that? I was trying to test if that method is returning a correct value. Im testing `opString()` in this way:     @Before
    public void setup() {
        when(JSONUtils.optString(JSONMock, "name")).thenReturn("Daniel");
        when(JSONUtils.optString(JSONMock, "city")).thenReturn(null);
        when(JSONUtils.optString(JSONMock, "lastname")).thenReturn("");
    }

    @Test
    public void optStringShouldReturnValidStringOnName() {

        String result = JSONUtils.optString(JSONMock, "name");
        Assert.assertEquals("Daniel",result);
    }

Comment: You create a mock that expects the two calls and returns what you want to be returned? Like in your setup method?

Comment: @Jägermeister How I do that with  JSON Object?

Answer (score 0):

Mock based testing always works like this:

1. You create some sort of mock object of a certain class
2. You "instruct" the mock for the expected calls and specify potential return values
3. You trigger your "code under test"; using that mock object as "input" to your code under test
4. You check that your "code under test" creates the expected outputs; depending on your mocking framework, you verify that your mock object saw the specified calls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how to create it but I don't know how to use it. First time doing tests. I read a lot but all of the are different examples to the one I have. I edited my questions, please check it. I try to test the method doing what you said. Not sure if I did it well.